# How to count number of HTTP requests made by AWS SDK for Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to create a test to make sure my class that wraps AWS S3 client requests some correct number of client.

```
class Wrapper {
    //
    private void buildClient() {
        this.client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(this.secret)
                .withRegion(this.region
                .build();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        while(checkSomething()) {
            client.doSomething();
            client.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this.

```
class WrapperTest {
    public testDoSomething() {
        wrapper.doSomething();
        assertTrue(numberOfHttpRequest, 3);
    }
}
```

For test purposes I can always mock the client object, but also I'm thinking of storing stats in production use for performance profiling (so collecting number of bytes might also be as useful as collecting number of HTTP requests themselves).

So far by reading the Java docs: 1) [ProgressEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ProgressEvent.html), 2) [Logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-logging.html), and 3) [AWSRequestMetrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/AWSRequestMetrics.html). But I'm not sure which one is more suitable in collecting number of requests and how to configure them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

**For unit testing** you definitely want to use [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) or scalamock or any Mocking API.

**Regarding metrics** for number of requests,

1) I would recommend collect the logs and send to elasticsearch (which is pretty common thesedays) where you can aggregate based on particular fields.

With `src/main/resource/log4j.properties` as below,

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, consoleLogs

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.consoleLogs=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleLogs.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleLogs.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c -  %m%n
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.request=DEBUG
```

The log4j logs for AWS SDK looks like below,

```
2017-06-01 11:56:58 DEBUG request:1137 - Sending Request: PUT https://samsa-repo.s3.amazonaws.com /sendme.log Headers: (User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.11.109 Mac_OS_X/10.11.6 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.111-b14/1.8.0_111 scala/2.11.8, amz-sdk-invocation-id: 9179e5c2-fee3-4e6e-abb9-b50f882f1966, Content-Length: 9, x-amz-storage-class: REDUCED_REDUNDANCY, Content-MD5: /UERdk1lrFHXgNJHTSd3QA==, Content-Type: application/octet-stream, ) 

2017-06-01 11:56:58 DEBUG request:87 - Received successful response: 200, AWS Request ID: 3695D599CB1FD794
```

For error reponse,

```
2017-06-01 13:58:24 DEBUG request:1572 - Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadDigest; Request ID: 684584BD135900F3), S3 Extended Request ID: Y1NowPaA/mhydTWaDBupS7o7CA/PkliiVKzmDrDQwENIOdrg049h8BZ+I6Pi1GC8TZqBq1AJGJg=
```

Since its easier to query the logs in JSON format, you can use following maven dependency to convert log4j logs in JSON format,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonevent-layout</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, change your log pattern to `net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1`,

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, consoleLogs

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.consoleLogs=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleLogs.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1
log4j.appender.consoleLogs.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c -  %m%n
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.request=DEBUG
```

The logs will look like below,

```
  {
    "@timestamp": "2017-06-01T21:05:37.204Z",
    "source_host": "M00974000.prayagupd.net",
    "file": "AmazonHttpClient.java",
    "method": "executeOneRequest",
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "line_number": "1137",
    "thread_name": "ScalaTest-run-running-PublishToSimpleStorageServiceSpecs",
    "@version": 1,
    "logger_name": "com.amazonaws.request",
    "message": "Sending Request: HEAD https://samsa-repo.s3.amazonaws.com / Headers: (User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.11.109 Mac_OS_X/10.11.6 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.111-b14/1.8.0_111 scala/2.11.8, amz-sdk-invocation-id: 39fd8121-b40d-cb48-a6ea-65cf580f569f, Content-Type: application/octet-stream, ) ",
    "class": "com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor",
    "mdc": {}
  },
  {
    "@timestamp": "2017-06-01T21:05:38.337Z",
    "source_host": "M00974000.prayagupd.net",
    "file": "AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java",
    "method": "handle",
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "line_number": "87",
    "thread_name": "ScalaTest-run-running-PublishToSimpleStorageServiceSpecs",
    "@version": 1,
    "logger_name": "com.amazonaws.request",
    "message": "Received successful response: 200, AWS Request ID: null",
    "class": "com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter",
    "mdc": {}
  }
```

After you send the logs to elasticsearch using forwarders like [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat), you can aggregate/search logs/ requests by value `Sending Request`.

If filebeat forwarder /elasticsearch/ kibana dashboard are overkill you might want to go aggregate logs via [AWS cloudwatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html).